# Determine buildType for other modules in Android

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-build-flavors, build-variant

I have 2 `buildType` for my `app` module named `release` and `debug`.

This module is depended on some other modules like `lib1`.

When I want to assemble an apk, I should run:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

In both of `build.gradle` file in `app` and `lib1`, I defined `buildTyle{ ... }` section and set `minifyEnabled true`.

but it seems gradle did not minify and shrink unused resources when I analyze signed apk for `release` type.

How can I determine which buildType should be use for my selected buildType for the `app` module? (when I run above command)

Answer (score 0):

I found this sentence from the [old document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication):

> By default a library only publishes its release variant. This variant will be used by all projects referencing the library, no matter which variant they build themselves.

so in my case, I should specify the requested configuration:

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseImplementation project(path: ':lib1', configuration: 'release')
}
```